# What is correct format of Node.js http.request options hostname parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https, hostname

I am trying to make a request to an Instagram API, I have troubles to understand why http.request hostname parameter from options.

Yet here is my code:

```
const http = require("http");
const https = require("https");

function requestInstagramData(){
    var options = {
      protocol: "https:",
      hostname: "https://api.instagram.com",
      path: "/v1/tags/fashion?access_token=3681332213.81b69f2.88020902f003411196c3f4423912f547",
      method: "GET"
    };
    var instaRequest = https.request(options);

     instaRequest.on("response", function(res){
      res.on("data", function(data){
        console.log("data has arrived");
      });

      console.log("response");
      console.log(res.statusCode);
      console.log(res.statusMessage);
    });

    instaRequest.end();

}
requestInstagramData();
```

This code doesnt work, but if I change hostname in options object to

```
hostname: "api.instagram.com"
```

It is working.

Why?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname

Comment: cause that's the hostname

Comment: The reason why I am asking is because I have seen numerous examples on the web that include http:// or https:// in hostname parameter. This is why I had the confusion.

Comment: I hope my answer helps. I noticed you got a couple of downvotes. I don't see this as a bad question. But if you like to improve the way you ask your questions on SO, please read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. http.request is a function like any other function. To use it properly you need to know what input it can accept, for this we usually check the documentation.
2. Documentation of http.request ([link](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)) says the input, the argument, must be an object  consisting of protocol, hostname, path and etc. These are all the standard components of http url scheme. You can check this article ([link](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)) that explains very clearly how those components are named.

Keeping those two in mind. It doesn't work with "http://" as that is the protocol and shouldn't be included in hostname.

Comment: The reason why I am asking is because I have seen numerous examples on the web that include http:// or https:// in hostname parameter. I am perfectly fine with checking the documentation, in fact I did that before posting the question.

Comment: @margarita oh I didn't know that part, adding that to question would make it more clear.

Comment: will do next time! Thank anyways!

Comment: @margarita in case you see different examples, it could be because of different versions of Node. I'm not sure, just guessing.

Comment: That's great, although I'd suggest moving the comment to under the question - the OP won't read it under your answer `:-)`.

Answer (score 3):

As you already found out when you tried "api.instagram.com", the *hostname* property is for specifying the host only, and host names by definition do not include a protocol. The protocol goes into the *protocol* property, just the way you have already done.